# PokeAPI - Fetching Pokemon Data

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I have just started to learn React and I am trying to build a PokeDex using the PokeAPI, but I am having an extremely hard time understanding how to fetch data from the API. I want to fetch the first 384 Pokemon related information. I have written this code below in componentDidMount() to extract the complete data in my main App class component, and push it to an array called pokemonArray which I will set to my state.

```
let pokemonArray = [];
/* First API fetch call to return names and URL's of first 384 Pokemon after promise is resolved.*/
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=384')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    let results = data.results;
    let promisesArray = results.map(result => {
      return fetch(result.url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => pokemonArray.push(data));
    })
    return Promise.all(promisesArray)
  }).then(this.setState({ pokemon: pokemonArray }, () => console.log('Main Pokemon State: ', this.state.pokemon)));

}
```

In my render method I want to pass this newly set state as a prop to a component called PokeList like so

```
<PokeList pokemon={this.state.pokemon} />
```

Once I pass it on and I try to render it out in my PokeList component like so

```
export const PokeList = ({ pokemon }) => {
    console.log(pokemon);

    return (
        <div className="pokecard-container">
            <h1>{pokemon[0].id}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I get an error that says **TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null**. The React Developer tools shows the state being populated with the retrieved values as well as the props being set as well, but it seems to consider it null. Could anyone please help out with this, it's been so frustrating to see this error out

Comment: your app doesn't have the `pokemon` array right away; it has to wait for the fetch, so you need to provide an initial value for pokemon and initial behavior before pokemon loads

Comment: Thank you, having a condition helped preventing it from erroring out again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, here's a modified working version:

```js
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=2')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    let results = data.results;
    let promisesArray = results.map(result => {
      return fetch(result.url).then(response => response.json());
    })
    return Promise.all(promisesArray);
  }).then((data) => this.setState({ pokemon: data }, () => console.log('Main Pokemon State: ', this.state.pokemon)));
```

And the explanation:

**Issue 1:**

Original code:

```js
let promisesArray = results.map(result => {
  return fetch(result.url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => pokemonArray.push(data));
})
return Promise.all(promisesArray)
```

The last `then()` callback returns the results of `pokemonArray.push(data)`. `Array.push` returns the length of the array, so `return Promise.all(promisesArray)` returns an array of array lengths.

Change it to:

```js
let promisesArray = results.map(result => {
  return fetch(result.url).then(response => response.json()); // Returns the data
})
return Promise.all(promisesArray)
```

**Issue 2:**

Original code:

```js
then(this.setState({ pokemon: pokemonArray }, () => console.log('Main Pokemon State: ', this.state.pokemon)));
```

You must supply a callback function to `then()`:

```js
.then((data) => this.setState({ pokemon: data }, () => console.log('Main Pokemon State: ', this.state.pokemon)));
```

You must also remember to initialize the state when your component is created:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    pokemon: [],
  };
}
```

Thus, when you render PokeList (`<PokeList pokemon={this.state.pokemon} />`), it will always receive an array, though it will be empty until the data is fetched.

Comment: Thank you so much these changes and your explanation helped me understand about the fetch API and Promises itself a lot better. I've made the changes, and put in a condition that displays a <h1>Loading</h1>, to prevent it erroring out, but it is getting stuck in that condition and the values aren't being fetched at all

Comment: This is my PokeList Component code, which for every entry in the data fetched, will map a new Pokemon Component out

`export const PokeList = ({ pokemonData }) => {
    console.log('Pokemon Data prop: ', pokemonData);

    if (pokemonData === undefined) {
        return (
            <h1>Loading Pokemon...</h1>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="pokecard-container">
            {pokemonData.map(pokemon => <Pokemon name={pokemon.name} sprite={pokemon.sprites.front_default} />)}
        </div>
    );
}`

Comment: This is my Pokemon Component Code that renders a card like component on the PokeList container

`export const Pokemon = ({ name, sprite }) => {
    return (
        <div className="poke-card">
            <img alt="Pokemon sprite" src={sprite} />
            <h3>{name}</h3>
        </div>
    );
}`

Comment: Here's a working example with the code from my answer, and your updated code: https://codesandbox.io/s/62110181-9u6sl Note that I've changed the name of the state variable (`this.state.pokemons`)

Comment: I figured out the problem ! I found that the props I was passing to the PokeList wasn't the same prop variable I destructured out in the PokeList component. It now works ! Thanks so much for your help with this. I have upvoted the answer but StackOverflow said it wouldn't be visible because I was still a novice user :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion to rewrite your fetching code :

```
class App extends Component{
 state = {
   pokemonArray : []
 }
 componentDidMount = () =>{
   fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=384')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
      let results = data.results;
      this.setState({ pokemonArray : [...results]})
     console.log("Here are my pokemons",   this.state.pokemonArray)
     })


 }
...
}
```

I'm using spread operator to copy the received data to the pokemonArray. You could pass then your array to the component as a prop. 
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, I will make use of the Spread operator !